# Which Vuforia feature should I use?

Tags: model, 3d, augmented-reality

A beginner here...asking a really basic question...

I have produced a 3D model (of a blue mussel) via photogrammetry and Reality capture.

What I would like to do is:

Use an illustration as an AR target, which will be printed on cardboard or a table cloth (see image https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoA9q.png) and then have my 3D model "pop up" on an iPad or iPhone. Just like in these photos: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfGcQ.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlGgx.jpg

Once the 3D model is on the screen, I would like to rotate it and also add text about the blue mussel, a video, etc.

My problem is:

I have tried using the Model target generator in Vuforia/Unity and all I end up with is a white outline of my 3D model. Am I using the wrong Vuforia feature? If yes, which one should I use?

With best wishes,
Susan